# nio2 and files attributes

Tags: java, attributes, backup, nio2

Just downloaded and installed NetBeans NetBeans IDE 7.2 (Build 201207171143);
Java: 1.7.0_03; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 22.1-b02. This is instead of Eclipse with JDK 6/ The main reason is because I ama starting a new project, that will have to access files and attributes (back up utility, including clearing the Archive flags - can anyone share experience?). However, the installation doesn't recognize java.nio.file.attribute, and sets error. Any idea?

Comment: It appears you are still using Java 6.

Comment: So how to change it? I started from clean system

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help:

---

### Windows

JDK is bundled with all the product installers and it's recommended that you will use the provided JDK version unless there are any specific issues.

32-bit JDK is located in **IDE_HOME\jre** directory and is used by the 32-bit product executable.

To run the IDE in 64-bit mode you will need to download and install 64-bit JDK (not JRE) distribution and install it yourself. IDE will find and use it from the registry when you run the 64-bit **.exe** file (available only for IntelliJ IDEA right now, other products can use the **.bat** file to run in 64-bit mode).

**<product>.exe** uses this JDK search sequence:

1. **IDEA_JDK** / **WEBIDE_JDK** / **PYCHARM_JDK** / **RUBYMINE_JDK** environment variable (depends on the product, **WEBIDE_JDK** applies to both WebStorm and PhpStorm)
2. **..\jre** directory
3. system **Registry**
4. **JDK_HOME** environment variable
5. **JAVA_HOME** environment variable

**idea64.exe** uses this JDK search sequence:

1. **IDEA_JDK_64** environment variable
2. **..\jre64** directory
3. system **Registry**
4. **JDK_HOME** environment variable
5. **JAVA_HOME** environment variable

It’s also possible to start the IDE with **<product>.bat** file located in the **bin** directory, it uses the following JDK search sequence:

1. **IDEA_JDK** / **WEBIDE_JDK** / **PYCHARM_JDK** / **RUBYMINE_JDK** environment variable (depends on the product)
2. **..\jre** directory
3. **JDK_HOME** environment variable
4. **JAVA_HOME** environment variable

Environment variable **must point to the JDK installation home directory**, for example:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_17
```

- /create-i4j-log command line switch can be used with the .exe to trace the JDK search sequence and find out why the specific JDK was chosen.
- The actual JDK version used by the IDE can be verified in Help | About dialog (open any project to access the menu).
- Define **IDEA_JDK** / **WEBIDE_JDK** / **PYCHARM_JDK** / **RUBYMINE_JDK** variable depending on the product to override the default version from **IDE_HOME\jre**.
- Use [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com/en/download) to add/edit the variables, it will detect incorrect paths.

---

From:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under